# TextQuality when using Graphics.FromImage

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to write a simple piece of text into a bitmap, using the System.Drawing.Graphics class.

When creating the Graphics class from an existing bitmap, using Graphics.FromImage(MyBitmap), the text being written looks like it's very bold (First line in picture below).

When drawing the same piece of text using a Graphics object that isn't created using the Graphics.FromImage method, the text looks as intended (Second line in picture below).

Using the debugger to examing the two different Graphics objects, reveals that their properties are identical, which makes me wonder why the Graphics.DrawText method creates two completely different results.

[image: Difference in formatting]

The code used to generate the screenshot above, looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1:Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        string                      text            = "1.000";
        Rectangle                   rectangle       = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
        System.Drawing.StringFormat stringFormat    = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);

        using(System.Drawing.Bitmap     bitmap      = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        using(System.Drawing.Graphics   graphics    = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        using(System.Drawing.Font       font        = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10))
        using(System.Drawing.SolidBrush drawBrush   = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black))
        {
            // Text looks very bold.
            graphics.DrawString(text, font, drawBrush, rectangle, stringFormat);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));

            // Text looks normal.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, drawBrush, new Rectangle(0, 20, 200, 200), stringFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to write the non-bold piece of text into a bitmap, such that I can use it elsewhere in my program.

Can anyone explain why the Graphics.DrawText method produces two different results, in the example code above, and how I can make the text output for the first Graphics object appear identical to the second Graphics object?

Comment: Pavel Minaev suggests that the text boldness comes from ClearType, not playing nice with alpha channel, which colors every antialiased pixel as completely black instead ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291185/803021)).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

Or any of the other TextRenderingHints