# Transparency key on Form distorts text box content

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form on which `TransparencyKey = Color.Black` is applied.
Form contains a TextBox and it's text ForeColor is Red.

When Form transparency is active, i.e. when `TransparencyKey = Color.Black` text looks somehow distorted it looks like some black background elements were not removed with `TransparencyKey`, when form is placed on any bright (white) background.

When form is presented on dark background, everything looks ok.

I have posted a [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD1OR.jpg) of my form to show you this behaviour (inserting image does not work for me right now I dunno why):

[image]

How to fix this so that text will be smooth as it should be independent on the background colour?

Comment: It's a nasty side effect of composition with text antialiasing, if I remember correctly you may draw the text by yourself (if disabling antialiasing is an option) or use a _true_ transparent window. Very related: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinFormLayeredWindow-23cdc375

Comment: Yea, when anti-aliasing is off text looks fine then...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antialiased text on transparent bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291061/antialiased-text-on-transparent-bitmap)

Comment: I would recommend, if possible, to use WPF because it's more appropriate for this behavior and scenario you have.